# Expectation related to Wiener process using strong Markov property

Tags: expectation, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Can you help me to understand a result I found in Krylov's book "Introduction to stochastic calculus".  First, I will introduce some notations:

1. $w_t,t\ge 0$ denotes a Wiener process.
2. $\mathcal{B}(R)$ denotes a Borel sigma-field on real line
3. $\tau(\omega)=\inf\{t: w_t\not\in (a,b)\}$ is the first time Wiener process exits the interval $(a,b)$.
4. $B_s=w_{\tau+s}-w_{\tau}$
5. $$\mathcal{F}_{\le \tau}^w:=\sigma\{ \{\omega: w_{s\wedge\tau}\in B\}, s\ge 0, B\in \mathcal{B}(R)\},$$
   $$
   \mathcal{F}_{\ge \tau}^w:=\sigma\{ \{\omega: w_{\tau+s}-w_\tau\in B\}, s\ge 0, B\in \mathcal{B}(R)\},
   $$

It is known that Wiener process has a strong Markov property, that is

- Let $\tau$ be almost surely finite  $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable stopping time  then sigma-fields $ \mathcal{F}_{\le \tau}^w$ and $ \mathcal{F}_{\ge \tau}^w$ are independent.*

**Theorem 1.** Let $u$ be twice continuosly differentable function defined on $[-\infty, \infty]$ and $u, u', u''$ are bounded functions. Then for every $\lambda> 0$ 
$$
u(0)=E\int_0^{\tau}e^{-\lambda t}\left(\lambda u(w_t)-\frac{1}{2}u''(w_t)\right)dt
$$
where $w_t, t\ge 0$  is a Wiener process.

I understood its proof. And based on theorem 1, the author obtains

**Theorem 2.**  Let $-\infty<a<0<b<+\infty$, $u$ be twice continuosly differentable function defined on $[a,b]$ and $u, u', u''$ are bounded functions. Then for every $\lambda\ge 0$ 
$$
u(0)=E\int_0^{\tau}e^{-\lambda t}\left(\lambda u(w_t)-\frac{1}{2}u''(w_t)\right)dt+Ee^{-\lambda\tau}u(w_\tau)
$$
where $w_t, t\ge 0$  is a Wiener process.

**Proof**

From theorem 1 we know that  (denoting $f=\lambda u-\frac 12 u''$)
$$
u(0)=E\int_0^{\tau}e^{-\lambda t}f(w_t)dt=E\int_0^{\tau}\ldots+E\int_\tau^{\infty}\ldots=
$$
$$
=E\int_0^{\tau}e^{-\lambda t}f(w_t)+E\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}e^{-\lambda \tau}f(w_{\tau+t})dt
$$
$$
=E\int_0^{\tau}e^{-\lambda t}f(w_t)+\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}Ee^{-\lambda \tau}f(w_{\tau}+B_t)dt=:I+J.
$$

It is easy to prove that the stopping time $\tau$ is $\mathcal{F}_{\le \tau}^w$-measurable. Evidently, $w_{\tau\wedge t}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{\le \tau}^w$-measurable as well, so is $w_{\tau\wedge t}1_{\tau<\infty}$. As $\tau$ is almost surely finite, 
$w_{\tau\wedge t}1_{\tau<\infty}\to w_{\tau}$ as $t\to \infty$, therefore $w_{\tau}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{\le \tau}^w$-measurable too.

**Question 1.** Howthe author futher splits $$Ee^{-\lambda \tau}f(w_{\tau}+B_t)=Ee^{-\lambda \tau}Ef(w_{\tau}+B_t)?$$

We can split it in case of independence, but I dont see it here.

Because if this is valid, then 
$$
J=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}Ee^{-\lambda \tau}Ef(w_{\tau}+B_t)dt=Ee^{-\lambda \tau}v(w_\tau)
$$
where 
$$
v(y):=E\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}f(y+B_t)dt
$$
Applying theorem 1 to this expectation, we obtain that $v(y)=u(y)$. So the theorem is proved for $\lambda >0$ (the theorem 1 had a limitation that $\lambda >0$).

**Question 2** Author says that we can pass to the limit when $\lambda\to 0$ using dominated convergence theorem provided that $E\tau<\infty$. I dont see why it is necessary to have the finiteness of $E\tau$ to apply dominated convergence.

I would be really, really thankful for your help.